# How to get items in the root of One Drive business using one drive API?

Tags: office365, onedrive, office365api, office365-restapi

I am able to log user into the one drive business account.And I am also able to get drive details.But how do I get the details of files and folders in the root of the one drive business account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*try this*

```
GET /drive/root/children
```

https://dev.onedrive.com/items/list.htm

*Possible response looks like*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "value": [
    {"name": "myfile.jpg", "size": 2048, "file": {} },
    {"name": "Documents", "folder": { "childCount": 4} },
    {"name": "Photos", "folder": { "childCount": 203} },
    {"name": "my sheet(1).xlsx", "size": 197 }
  ],
  "@odata.nextLink": "https://..."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the détails of a drive is made with the /root/children path :

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/children?$select=name
```

Comment: Since he's referring to business it should actually be `https://histenant-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/root/children?select=name`, but I'll upvote cause it's easy enough to translate between business and consumer :)

Comment: I want to list all children not any specific children.How do I do that?

Comment: The above request provided by @Brad is used to list all children under the user's default Drive, $select=name is only show the name property , are you have any error with above request ?